# What is the relationship between CPU tick and hertz?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-usage

Some unix tools (using /proc) provide CPU time via ticks.But I want to measure CPU usage in Hertz.

So, what is the relationship between CPU tick vs Hertz?

Comment: If you are talking about `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` then there is no relationship. This is just a fixed constant (but might vary between different systems).

Comment: @marcos.borunda Why it is not related. I want to write script to convert this? Thats what I asked.


scai thanks. I was looking at the /proc/[pid]/stat in Ubuntu